# Mono for Android: ListView casting wrong values to toast

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, onitemclick

**My list.ItemClick:**

```
lstText.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) 
{
    var userIdTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtUserId);
    var fetchUserId = userIdTextView.Text;

    sUserId = fetchUserId;

    Toast.MakeText(this, sUserId, ToastLength.Short).Show();

};
```

On list view the `(Resource.Id.txtUserId)` is different on each list item. When I click on toast it always passes the same value from the first item in the list. How can I fix that?

Please provide solution or hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindViewById` should be used to find the resourse id in the context of each item in the listview context, which is `args.View`.

```
lstText.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) 
{
    var userIdTextView = args.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtUserId);
    var fetchUserId = userIdTextView.Text;

    sUserId = fetchUserId;

    Toast.MakeText(this, sUserId, ToastLength.Short).Show();

};
```